# Rendering of zero width table cells in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, html-email, outlook-2010, email-client

**First off:**
I hate Outlook :)

**Here is why:**
I am trying to send an email with the following structure (this is just a simplified example so please don't tell me "Just get rid of the middle `td`s")

```
<table width="400">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td width="200"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"></td>
       <td width="0"></td>
       <td width="0"></td>
       <td width="200"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is, that the two `td`s in the middle lead to a space between the two pictures as you can see in this screenshot http://i48.tinypic.com/6i8rvk.png

I feel like I have already tried everything possible.

- cellpadding = 0, cellspacing = 0, border = 0 on table
- setting the width of every td with inline css
- adding border-collapse: collapse to all tds and the table
- adding margin:0, padding:0; border 0; to all tds in inline css
- setting the font-size and line-height to 0 in inline css

Nothing worked.

**Side notes:**
If there is only one empty table cell in the middle, the rendering is fine. So it seems as if each `td` only accounts for half a pixel
This is already a simplified example and I cannot change the structure of the table meaning that I have to find a workaround for the rendering problems rather than fixing the rather unpretty coding style unfortunately.

**Testing**
Here is my testing environment - feel free to play around with it: http://putsmail.com/d58ffa01c4b3e29123baab00754716

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have continued trying to solve this problem - **nothing** (I have tried every proposal here and more) worked.
In the end I went the more difficult but also the cleanest way I believe and wrote a script that removes all empty columns and all empty rows with an xsl transformation. Now it works in Outlook 2003 - 2010.

Answer (score 3):

try putting padding-left and/or padding-right to the tds containing the images, as inline css.

Latest edit: try this --

`<tr>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse; margin:0;padding:0; border:0" align="right" width="200"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0; border:0" border="0"></td>
<td style="width: 0px;line-height: 0px; font-size: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;padding:0;margin:0;border:0" width="0"></td>
<td style="width: 0px;line-height: 0px; font-size: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;padding:0;margin:0;border:0" width="0"></td>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse; margin:0;padding:0; border:0" align="left" ><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0; border:0" border="0"></td></tr>`

i removed the width from tds containing images, hence it takes the default width of the images.

Comment: I did this already - http://putsmail.com/d58ffa01c4b3e29123baab00754716 It doesn't work.

Comment: i put padding-right:10px in the first `<td>` in your test environment and it looks fine. is it not working on outlook?

Comment: I tested the above for outlook 2003, 2007 & 2010, all look good. I use getResponse.com for my testing for different email clients, its free :)

Comment: Can you post the source code that worked? I would like to test it and see it in action in my Outlook installation :)

Comment: `<tr>
<td style="width: 200px; border-collapse: collapse; margin:0;padding-right:10px; border:0" align="right" width="200"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0; border:0" border="0"></td>
<td style="width: 200px; border-collapse: collapse; margin:0;padding:0; border:0" align="left" width="200"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0; border:0" border="0"></td></tr>`

Comment: Ok, there are a couple of problems with this code: 1. I am trying to eliminate the space between the two pictures, so I really don't want to set a padding of 10px, 2. you deleted the two empty `td`s in the middle - without them there is no problem (I knew that from the beginning). In conclusion it solve my problem at all

Comment: may i ask, whats the need for 0 width tds?

Comment: it's the given structure that I cannot influence. I wish I could just get rid of them but since the code is generated automatically and in reality is much, much more complicated than my simplified example it is impossible to just delete them. So I have to find a work around.

Comment: did that lastest edit work? if so, can i get the bounty pls :)

Answer (score 2):

Outlook doesn't like hiding content ;-) But what should work - add some conditional code:

```
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed">
                <tr>
                  <td style="width:217px" valign="top">
                    column 1
                  </td>
                  <!--[if !mso]><!--><td style="line-height:0;max-height:0;width:0;overflow:hidden;font-size:0;display:none" valign="top">
                    hidden column 2
                  </td>
                  <!--<![endif]--><td valign="top">
                    column 3
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

To hide it from outlook, the comments around the column with [!mso / endif] are enough. However you may want to hide in also in outlook.com, gmail.com and some others - for this the other styles are included. Don't forget to restore the settings in mobile view with media queries.

Good luck
Oleg

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the `<td>`s on the same line?  That is, removing the linebreak between elements?

(inner element linebreaks are ignored)

```
<td>Foo
</td><td>
Bar</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does "display: none" help?

```
<table width="400">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td width="200"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"></td>
       <td width="0" style="display:none"></td>
       <td width="0" style="display:none"></td>
       <td width="200"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Btw, I did not suffer your problem on Outlook 2003, so I cannot verify it.

Comment: Er... thanks for the bounty anyway I guess. Does that mean it solved anything on Outlook 2003? Have you tried combining this and coder1984's solution for 2007/2010?